# Передача данных между скриптом для PHP cli, и веб страницей

Tags: php, stdin

Есть скрипт php, для командной строки, и есть веб страничка.
Скрипт из командной строки отлично работает, принимает данные от пользователя, и продолжает функционировать. Данные принимаются посредством trim(fgets(STDIN)), также отлично работает readline.
Есть различные переменные которые требуют ввода данных на разном этапе выполнения скрипта.
Появилась необходимость в веб интерфейсе для данного скрипта!начальные переменные получается задать посредством формы, и обработчиком. Вот как выполнить ввод в последующие переменные?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию `shell_exec`, она позволяет выполнять команды через оболочку (например, bash) и вернуть вывод в виде строки.

Подробнее: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php